# How to compare single array to one part of multidimensional in PHP

Tags: php

I want to fetch one column from database and i want to compare with a single array.
If any value equal than doesn't print else print all values of single array.

Comment: Please provide the code you got so far and array example.

Comment: So, to confirm as the last bit is slightly garbled. You want to fetch data from a db, and for each line you want to test if a specific field is within a array, if it is print it, otherwise print all the contents of the single array?

Comment: PHP has a function for that, please scan the manual first: http://php.net/manual/function.array-intersect-assoc.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

```
$array = array(); // Your array
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM mytable");
$response = false;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  if (in_array($row['name'], $array)) {
    $response = true;
  }
}
if ($response === false) {
    print_r($array);
}
```